# When Grouping RadGridView Append header data and Row Data

Tags: wpf, telerik, radgrid

While grouping in the Telerik RadGridview , the group header has to be appended with column data. Like "Name : James", where "Name " is column header and "James " is column data. Kindly share your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Not really clear what you asking but try this:

```
</Columns>
   <GroupByExpressions>
      <telerik:GridGroupByExpression>
        <SelectFields>
          <telerik:GridGroupByField FieldName="Name"/>
        </SelectFields>
     <GroupByFields>
      <telerik:GridGroupByField FieldName="Name"/>
     </GroupByFields>
      </telerik:GridGroupByExpression>
   </GroupByExpressions>
```

Comment: when I group the data, the data displayed in the grid for the grouped column, should include the column header of it. Suppose, "Product Type" is the text in column header , all the rows should append "Product Data :" along with the column data.

Comment: @ArunVijai Have you tried the above snippet? It should return you an header like Name:James and inside that block all the James names

Comment: <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>  <GroupByExpressions>                    <telerik:GridGroupByExpression><SelectFields>                               <telerik:GridGroupByField FieldName="LocationTypeFullName"/></SelectFields><GroupByFields> <telerik:GridGroupByField FieldName="LocationTypeFullName"/></GroupByFields></telerik:GridGroupByExpression></GroupByExpressions> </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>

Comment: @ArunVijai, What do you mean?

Comment: Below is the code I tried and this returns the missing reference error. <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>  <GroupByExpressions>                    <telerik:GridGroupByExpression><SelectFields>                               <telerik:GridGroupByField FieldName="LocationTypeFullName"/></SelectFields><br><GroupByFields><br><telerik:GridGroupByField FieldName="LocationTypeFullName"/><br></GroupByFields></telerik:GridGroupByExpression><br></GroupByExpressions> <br></telerik:RadGridView.Columns>

Comment: not sure what you are doing. the syntax shall be the one I posted in my answer then you can change the name of the columns

Comment: This is for WPF application. and I could not find the GroupByExpressions there in my list of classes